# Styling in OpenLayers2: unknown symbol name

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, sld

I'm using **Geoserver 2.8.1** and **OpenLayers 2** to visualize cartographies, [the geoserver documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.8.x/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/pointsymbols.html) indicates I can use extra symbols in my **SLD**, the "*shape://oarrow*" for example :

```
 <Mark>
   <WellKnownName>shape://oarrow</WellKnownName>
     <Fill>
       <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
     </Fill>
 </Mark>
```

But when I try to load this kind of style, I get this error from **OpenLayers.js**:

> Uncaught Error: shape://oarrow is not a valid symbol name

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [SLD standard](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sld) says that renderers must support 6 well known names (circle, square, cross, x, triangle and star) any other names are extensions to the standard and may or may not be supported by a renderer.

So OpenLayers is correct when it says that it doesn't know what the symbol is **but** it is incorrect when it throws an error. The standard requires (p40 SLD1.0) that the render skip over unknown (graphics and) marks and draw the next graphic item, and if all else fails draw a small gray square (the default mark).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any way to make OpenLayers to "understand" the SLD extensions normally supported by Geoserver ?

Comment: You would need to write javascript for this, as OpenLayers-3 is now in development I doubt any one will look at adding new features to OpenLayers-2 but check with the developers.